# Tokenizing XML output using Java DOM parser - multiple child node values

Tags: java, xml, dom, domparser

in my expressions tab in Eclipse, I am able to see that the following output

```
\nmilk product, cultured\ncow milk\ncheese farm\n
```

by calling

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("XMLTAG").item(0).getTextContent());
```

How to tokenize the string using `\n` using `indexof` such that I can have separate string values ie:

```
String dairy1 = "milk product, cultured";
String dairy2 = "cow milk"
String dairy3 = "cheese farm"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way should be

```
String[] toks =
eElement.getElementsByTagName("XMLTAG").item(0).getTextContent().split( "\n" );
```

The empty element [0] must be skipped if the \n is always at the beginning.